# System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.'

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

We are invoking a dotnet standard dll that calls GetCurrent on WindowsIdentity. It works fine in a dotnet core application, but as soon as you import it into a dotnet framework (4.7.2) application is gives this error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.'
```

This issue persists, despite having been raised on the dotnet/standard github issues forum a few months ago:
https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1279

Comment: so this is specifically when you're *targeting* netstandard, but *running* on net472? does the library currently dual-target? or does it *only* target netstandard? if the latter: could you *make* it dual-target? i.e. `<TargetFrameworks>net472;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>` (it *sounds* like a bait-and-switch failure with a transitive dependency)

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell - the host app was targetting net472, the library was only targetting netstandard.  Making it dual-target as you suggested worked nicely, many thanks :-)   Feel free to make this a proper answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *sounds* like a problem with the way assembly resolution works between build-time vs run-time (which works via a "bait and switch" approach). When you get this kind of problem with transitive dependencies, the first thing to try is to have your library *join the bait and switch party*, by *declaring* that it may have different needs on different TFMs. This is pretty easy, fortunately; it often just means changing:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

This is now a multi-targeting package. When an *application* (exe, etc) is built (not a library - only applications), it checks the entire dependency tree and figures out what the most appropriate version of the dll is *for each package separately*. This means that if the application is targeting `net472`, `net48`, etc - they'll get your `net472` build, which probably has subtly different onward chains itself (even if you can't see them). If the application is targeting .NET Core, they'll get the `netstandard2.0` version of your package, and whatever dependencies *that* has.

Note: for best coverage, you *might* want to drop the TFM a bit to:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

The reason for this is that `net461`, `net462` etc *claim* to be able to handle `netstandard2.0` - so if an application is targeting `net461` and your package targets `netstandard2.0;net472`, then the "best" match is `netstandard2.0`, which presumably still won't work. You can have as many as you need, of course (and even change the onward references for each) - perhaps:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.0;net461;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

*Usually* you only add TFMs to either:

- exploit extra features that are available on a particular TFM, or
- reach platforms that aren't covered by your current list, or
- fix bait-and-switch/dependency problems